# Get image size with filesize() php

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code

```
$img=("http://dreamhouse.gocrm.uz/".$image->path);

$size=filesize($img);
```

I want to know image size but I get like this error "local.ERROR: filesize(): stat failed for ..."

what I should do pls give advise

Comment: The file needs to be on disk (your disk) for `filesize()` to work.

Comment: Please, in future, show us ALL of the error message not just what you think might be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is distant, you must download it first using `file_get_contents(...url...)` or cURL.

```
$local_path = '/path/to/temporary/file';
$image_contents = file_get_contents("http://dreamhouse.gocrm.uz/" . $image->path);
file_put_contents($local_path, $image_contents);
$size = filesize($local_path);
unlink($local_path);
```

You may also calculate size from `$image_contents` without using a tierce file, with mbstring functions.